# In AutoMapper can you apply the same value resolver to multiple members

Tags: c#, automapper

I have some mapping code as follows

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CalculationQueryResult, CalculationViewModel>()
       .ForMember(poco => poco.NomineeFee, 
                   opt => opt.ResolveUsing<FormattedCurrencyInt>()
         .FromMember(m => m.NomineeFee))

       .ForMember(poco => poco.TotalContributions, 
                   opt => opt.ResolveUsing<FormattedCurrencyInt>()
         .FromMember(m => m.TotalContributions))

       .ForMember(poco => poco.EquityInjection, 
                   opt => opt.ResolveUsing<FormattedCurrencyInt>()
         .FromMember(m => m.EquityInjection))

  // ... SNIP Lots more members mapped with Formatted Currency Resolver
```

As you can see I am mapping multiple members using the same resolver to convert a integer to a formatted currency string.  I'm doing this for the vast majority but not all members on my poco class.

All these members would map using convention based mapping if I didn't need to keep repeating these types. Its a massive amount of code to write for a simple task.

Is there any way to override the default behaviour for converting an int to a string for a single map and then do custom .ForMembers where I want something different.  Such as this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CalculationQueryResult, CalculationViewModel>()
            .SetDefault<int,string>(opt => opt.ResolveUsing<FormattedCurrencyInt>())
            .ForMember(poco => poco.Count, x=>x.MapFrom(s => s.Count.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply the same value resolver to multiple members in they way described.

It can override the default mapping from int to string for all mappings, as suggested by Georg Patscheider  but this is likely to have side effects worse than the original problem.

You will have to write out the mapping line by line.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10488443)

Comment: Sometimes the answer is "that's not possible".  This answer isn't adding anything additional to my question. The other answer offered doesn't answer my question either.

Comment: So then why did you post the answer if it isn't adding anything? Some of us here will review low quality answers and make comments about them. That is part of how this site works where I'd suggest putting in some explanation or justification for why you think that as otherwise it is just an opinion and everyone will have one of those. "I think I can fly" would be something that I could state and without adding more to it could be either true or false. If I'm in a helicopter or plane then I may well fly well whereas if I tried to flap my arms to fly that wouldn't work so well is the why.

Comment: I've expanded the answer as requested.  I think a "That's not Possible" answer does add value when the context is question has an answer that  does not address the question and an unhelpful "PS..... "

Answer (score 4):

You can create the default mapping as

```
Mapper.CreateMap<int, string>().ConvertUsing<FormattedCurrencyIntConverter>();

private class FormattedCurrencyIntConverter : TypeConverter<int, string> {
    protected override string ConvertCore(int numericValue) {
        return numericValue.ToString("C2");  // format here ...
    }
}
```

But beware that this mapping rule will be applied for all integers! Overriding this rule for certain members is probably possible, but I didn't test it.

PS: I recommend to write down all mapping rules explicitly and don't rely on convention based mappings. If a property gets renamed only on one side, the convention based mapping breaks, but an explicit rule can be refactored automatically by the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, as you say that will apply the conversion to every Map which doesn't really help me.  I want to apply it to a specific map.